# How can an image converted to binary be converted back to an image?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have converted an image in binary but i am unable to convert it back to an image. The command imwrite is not working.
Here are a few lines of code

```
info=imfinfo('map.jpg')
I=imread('map.jpg');
b=dec2bin(I);
```

Does anybody have a solution?
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "an image in binary"? Black and white, _i.e._ just binary values of ones and zeros?

Comment: yeah ones and zeros. 67500×8 is the size and type is char.i need to convert it back to an image file

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mat2gray`.

```
BinaryMatrix = eye(500);
imwrite(mat2gray(BinaryMatrix), 'imagefile.png', 'png');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can visualize the image in matlab you could try `print`, this will save a figure to a file (jpeg by default IIRC)

Answer (score 0):

Cast it to no longer be an array of logicals:

```
Inew = uint8(I);
imshow(Inew);
```